# Problem in PHP with multiple function arguments in a form's "value" attribute

Tags: php, html, forms, arguments, user-defined-functions

I am attempting to use a function in PHP to echo a value for a form element's "value" attribute.  The problem is that if I pass more than one argument, this form element and the rest of the HTML on my page will not display, although no errors are returned.  With one argument, the function works as expected.  The function should receive a value and a formatting constant and echo the formatted value to the form element's "value" attribute.

Additional notes: Single quotes do not change the result.  If I remove the second argument, it processes fine.

```
function myFunction($input, $format)
    {           
        if(isset($format))
        {
            switch($format)
            { 
                case "num":
                    if(is_num($input))
                        {
                            echo number_format($input);
                            break;  //only breaks if the input & data type match, else it will return an error with catch
                        }
                case "percent":
                     if(is_num($input))
                     {
                            echo number_format($input, 2);
                            break;  //only breaks if the input & data type match, else it will return an error with catch
                     }
                default:
                    echo "Error: either format doesn't match the variable type or format type is undefined. Input: $input; Format: $format";
            }
        }
        echo number_format($input);
    }
...
<input type="text" name="M7" id="M7" value="<?php myFunction($value, "num"); ?>" onkeypress="return validateNumber(event)" readonly="true" />
```

Comment: It appears to be fine, and it should work. Please show us some more code so that we can get a better picture of what is going on.

Comment: I added the full code of the function.  Let me know if you need anything more?

Comment: `is_num` is not a PHP function. Have you defined it yourself?

Comment: nope, that should have been is_numeric() - that fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
<input type="text" name="M7" id="M7" value="<?php myFunction($value, \"num\"); ?>" onkeypress="return validateNumber(event)" readonly="true" />
```

## Else

```
<input type="text" name="M7" id="M7" value="<?php myFunction($value, 'num'); ?>" onkeypress="return validateNumber(event)" readonly="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  With the first change, I get an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"num\"); ?>"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in D:\...

Comment: It's a php block so nothing will be printed unless php does. I think quote is not the problem.

Comment: With the second change of using 'num' instead of "num", I get the same result: the HTML ceases to display from this point in the code onward.

Comment: I think it's the comma in the function that begins to throw everything off, I just don't understand why or how to fix it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

From comments by Sverri M. Olsen:
is_num is not a PHP function. Have you defined it yourself?

nope, that should have been is_numeric() - that fixed it, thank you! – RWC

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

put single quotes for num string

```
 <input type="text" name="M7" id="M7" value="<?php myFunction($value, 'num'); ?>" onkeypress="return validateNumber(event)" readonly="true" />
```

Answer (score -1):

It may be becoz of "double quotes" around num. Try to change it to single quotes